Orbit 57069N Rain and Freeze Sensor with Rain Bird ARC6 App-Based Indoor Smart Irrigation WiFi Timer/Controller
I have 2 stations sprinklers, now combined into one as few sprinklers are closed/not required. I am considering to replace my old hard wired manual controller with Rain Bird ARC6 App-Based Indoor Smart Irrigation WiFi Timer/Controller. And to add Orbit 57069N Rain and Freeze Sensor (it is cheaper than Rain Bird's rain sensor). Will the combination work?

The Rain Bird ARC6 manual reports there are two "sens" [sic] screws normally jumpered, and says:

Rain Bird controllers are only compatible with normally closed rain or rain/freeze sensors.

It appears that the sensor attached should act like a switch: Closed, the ARC6 operates; Open, the ARC6 stops operating.
The Orbit 57069N website does not have a manual that can be easily found, but does say:

a wire runs up to 30 ft. to the rain sensor port of the irrigation controller.

Contact Orbit to see if the sensor acts like a switch, where when there is no rain or freeze conditions, the internal contacts are "closed" (or if it connects the two sensor wires together, if the Orbit phone person doesn't know what "closed" means). If so, the Orbit should work with the Rain Bird.

As per couple of reviews on Amazon for this device, it does act normally closed.
Works like a charm (but had to add a small relay to invert the sensor's "Normally Closed = Dry" operation...) https://www.amazon.com/Orbit-Sprinkler-System-Freeze-Sensor/product-reviews/B000A7SPPU/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_kywd?pageNumber=1&filterByKeyword=normally+closed
